# Retention Policy base on selection

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention

I need to create a SharePoint online retention policy on the document library to keep documents forever. To do this, I am using the Office365 compliance center. The condition is based on a choice column. For instance, if the users select Policy, then that records need to keep forever. Is this something that we can achieve using the Office365 compliance center?

Kind Regards

Comment: Just a note from my experience relying on end users to tag stuff does not work out so well.  I'd look at retention from a library or site level.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, you have to **create a retention policy** in O365 complaince center. Select "Retain items forever" in Define retention settings.
   [image]
2. **Publish the retention label** on your tenant.
3. Go to the document library, click Automate > Power Automate > See your flows, create a Automated cloud flow and set trigger as When a file is created or modified.
4. Built a flow like below. I invoked the Send an HTTP Request action from a Power Automate Flow to make a REST call against the document using the SetComplianceTag method.
   [image]

Yes/No is a Yes/No type column in my document library. You can modify the condition in the flow based on your own choice column.
[image]

Details of the Send an HTTP Request action:

- Method: `POST`
- Uri: `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<libraryname>')/items(@{triggerOutputs()?['body/ID']})/SetComplianceTag()`
- Headers:

  ```
   Accept application/json;odata=nometadata
   Content-Type application/json;odata=nometadata
  ```
- Body:

  ```
   {
       "complianceTag":"<RetentionPolicyName>",
       "isTagPolicyHold":false,
       "isTagPolicyRecord":false,
       "isEventBasedTag":false,
       "isTagSuperLock":false,
       "isUnlockedAsDefault":false
   }
  ```

5. Now the retention policy can be automatically applied when a file is created or modified in the library and the Yes/no field of the file is set to Yes.

Comment: Thanks Allen, we using E5 license and I was wondering with this license, is there any limitation with how many records we can have?